# Reduce Tiling within Perlin Noise Texture

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js, noise

With the code below I am generating a canvas full of noise. I would like this noise to be resolution agnostic. (appear visually the same at all resolutions) - The code below provides this, but the noise which is pulled from [Rune Madsens's Noise](https://github.com/runemadsen/rune.noise.js/blob/master/src/noise.js) seems to tile.

Can anyone suggest a way that I might make it less of an obvious repeating pattern, yet still keep it looking the same at all resolutions.

```
let grain_index = 0;
let grain_scale = 0.0025;

for (let ypos = 0; ypos < rd.canvas.height; ypos++) 
{
    for (let xpos = 0; xpos < rd.canvas.width; xpos++) 
    {
        let samplex = xpos  / (rd.canvas.height * grain_scale);
        let sampley = ypos  / (rd.canvas.width  * grain_scale);
        let samplez = 0;

        let lum = rd.noise.get(samplex, sampley, samplez) * 255;

        grain_imagedata[grain_index + 0] = lum;
        grain_imagedata[grain_index + 1] = lum;
        grain_imagedata[grain_index + 2] = lum;
        grain_imagedata[grain_index + 3] = 96;
        
        grain_index += 4;
    }
}
```

[image: Output from the above code - Noise appears tiled]

Comment: Maybe modify samplez with a low frequency too?

Comment: Why not [ask Rune](https://github.com/runemadsen/rune.noise.js/issues)

Comment: @mplungjan I asked here, as I was hoping it would be quicker with a larger readership and my situation is time critical. I did this with the usual sense of foreboding and dread that comes with posting on StackOverflow as it generally seems to be comprised of a stark contrast of some of the most and least helpful people on the internet.

Comment: @AKX thanks for your comment - I suspected this might be the solution, but I cannot for the life of me think of what to use.

Comment: I only suggested it because I do not have a clue, but still wanted to help

Comment: If you gave us a [mcve] perhaps someone with more math knowledge could tweak your example

Comment: You might also want to try another noise implementation such as https://github.com/josephg/noisejs ...

Comment: I did, and it works perfectly, thanks.